# An alternative proof without multiplier theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given $f\in \mathcal{S}'$ and $\phi\in C_0^\infty$, with $\operatorname{Supp}\phi = \{1 \leq \xi \leq 2\}$. Define $\phi_j = \phi(2^{-j}\cdot)$.

We have if $\phi_k*f\in L^p$, then for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\|J^s\phi_k*f\|_p\leq C 2^{js}\|\phi_k*f\|_p,$$
where $J^s f:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\xi|)^{s/2}\widehat{f}).$

The lemma is from [this book](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Interpolation_spaces.html?id=jB3vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), P140. In the proof in the book, it used techniques from Fourier multipliers. I am looking for a self contained proof, which may employ a stronger assumption that $f\in B_{p,q}^s$.

Comment: For $p=2$ a self-contained proof is easy to give. But in general, this is not such a simple fact, and the assumption on $f$ does not really help: it could even be a Schwarz function, and we'd still have the same problem. The operator $J^s$ is defined by a Fourier multiplier, and we need some theory to somehow bound it on $L^p$ for $p\ne 2$. ... You may want to ask [Montgomery-Smith](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/22016), who wasn't active on MSE when you posted this question.